# I get this error when I try to run this code: MongoParseError: options poolsize, usenewurlparse are not supported

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mern

This message shows up when I try to run this code. I'm following a tutorial online and am new to MERN stack.

```
import app from "./server.js";
import mongodb from "mongodb";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config(); /* configure dotenv */
const MongoClient =
  mongodb.MongoClient; /* get access to MongoClient from MongoDB */
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000; //connect port

//Connect to MongoDB
MongoClient.connect(process.env.RESTREVIEWS_DB_URI, {
  poolSize: 50,
  wtimeout: 2500,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
})
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  })
  .then(async (client) => {
    //app.listen is used to start our web server, after connecting to the DB
    app.listen(port, () => {
      //we're listening at the port
      console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about remove `poolSize: 50` and `useNewUrlParser: true` since the error told you they are not supported anymore ?

Comment: what if I want to set the limit of users to 50? I cross checked, and that's the key used to set that limit. Same with useNewUrlParser (I just learned that they've deprecated this)

Comment: Use `maxPoolSize` (with `useUnifiedTopology=true`) ? [FYI](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/4.0/docs/CHANGES_4.0.0.md)